# Preventing log4j from Rolling over all Loggers in a config file at Startup

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a single java class (a device controller) that is being used to create 5 separate processes.  Each of the processes is assigned an identifier.  I would like each of the processes to write to its own log file based on its assigned identifier.  I have all of the appenders and loggers defined in a shared log4j2.xml config file.

Issue:  When I start the first device controller, it successfully writes to the correct log file.  However, when I start the second device controller, log4j will roll-over all of the loggers in the log4j2.xml config file and will only write to the log file assigned to the new process.  All of the log messages for the first process will go to the rolled-over log file, but new messages are no longer written to its newly rolled-over log file.

(OS: Linux, log4j version: 2.8.2)

Below is an abbreviated version of the log4j2.xml config file that I used.

```
    ...
    <Appenders>
        ...
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile-1" fileName="/logs/EPDU/Device-1.log" filePattern="/logs/EPDU/Device-1_%d{dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                ...
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policy>
                <OnStartUpTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policy>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax"/>
        </RollingFile>
        ...
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile-5" fileName="/logs/EPDU/Device-5.log" filePattern="/logs/EPDU/Device-5_%d{dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                ...
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policy>
                <OnStartUpTriggeringPolicy minSize="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB"/>
            </Policy>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="device-1" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-1" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        ...
        <Logger name="device-5" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile-5" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```

The Logger variable is initialized and assigned in the main method after the device identifier is determined similar to the code below:

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

    public class DeviceController {

        private satic Logger deviceLogger;

        public DeviceController(Param param1, Param param2){
            ...
        }

        ...

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            /**
             *  Fancy code to find device identifier...
             *  String loggerName = (results of fancy code is "device-[1..5]");
             */

            deviceLogger = LogManager.getLogger(loggerName);

            deviceLogger.info("Start logging stuff in device log.");

            new DeviceController(param1, param2);
        }

     ...

    }
```

How can I prevent all of the loggers from rolling over, but instead leave the currently running processes/logs alone as the next process and log is started?

Note: I tried to provide a "Goldilocks" amount of detail to explain the problem.  Sorry if I provided too much or not enough information.

Comment: Not sure what's the solution yet but from the [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html), I believe I've noticed something already: I think it should be `<AppenderRef ... />` and not `<AppendRef ... />` in your Loggers definition. Even wondering how it could work this way.

Comment: @Maaaatt you are correct, that was a typo I made transposing the config here and I corrected the question above; however, it was correct in the actual config file (on the other system).  I am confident the log4j2.xml file is formatted correctly, but I don't know if it is configured correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show a little bit more of your code? I think your issue comes from the fact you have a static logger. So from your above snippet, I believe you overwrite for each new DeviceController the deviceLogger with a new Logger with the next identifier you fetch. I would guess that at the end, all your logs are being appended to your device-5 log file, aren't they?

Side note, I think it's good practice to use the sl4f interface to declare your logger but then assigned the log4j implementation to your logger.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by using the sl4f interface to declare you logger.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is any additional code I can add without muddying the waters.  You may be correct and the logger may be getting overwritten; however, I don't see any additional logging, but I may need to artificially invoke logging to test for sure.

Comment: It's not really to solve your problem but it's always better to program to an interface. You could later on easily change your logging framework if you needed too. Here is the slf4j [manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) describing well what I mean.